# Unable to access Redfish on HPE Superdome 2

Tags: ilo, hpe, redfish

I'm trying to explore Redfish API using a [Python client (python-ilorest-library)](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/python-ilorest-library) from HPE, however, it seems to be failing to connect with the RedFish service. I'm getting following error message:

```
redfish.rest.v1.ServerDownOrUnreachableError: Server not reachable, return code: 404
```

I've tried both the suggested prefixes:

`https://{{oa-ilo}}/rest/v1` and `https://{{oa-ilo}}/redfish/v1`

Though there is no clear documentation around whether RedFish is available for HPE Superdome 2 servers, is there something required at the configuration level on the server? or RedFish is not supported on this specific server atall? If this is not available, what can be the other possible alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Superdome 2 is an iLO 3 based server which [predated Redfish support](https://web.archive.org/save/https://h22208.www2.hpe.com/eginfolib/servers/docs/HPRestfultool/iLo4/data_model_reference.html).

For iLO 3 you will want [HPONCFG](https://web.archive.org/web/20181212020928/https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=a00040436en_us) which is the legacy tool for scripting.